# Understanding Namespacing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run my tests I get an error undefined constant Admin::Blog::Category.

The model is defined like so:

```
module Blog
  class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
  end
end
```

When i try to call it from my admin controller I get the error. The controller is defined like so:

```
module Admin
  module Blog
    class CategoriesController < Admin::AdminController
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

My question is this name-spaced incorrectly or how do I call the Blog::Category model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call it as `::Blog::Category.all`, for e.g. to get all categories inside the controllers. A litle insight how the search will be happening.

```
module Blog
  class Category
    #...
  end
end

module Admin
  module Blog
    class Categories
      def self.class_name
        Module.nesting
      end
    end
  end
end

Admin::Blog::Categories.class_name
# >> [Admin::Blog::Categories, Admin::Blog, Admin]
```

After this it will search on the toplevel. Let's see 2 examples:

```
module Blog
  class Category
    #...
  end
end

Category = 12

module Admin
  module Blog
    class Categories
      def self.const_value
        Category
      end
    end
  end
end

Admin::Blog::Categories.const_value # => 12
```

and, now...

```
module Blog
  class Category
    #...
  end
end

Category = 12

module Admin
  Category = 11
  module Blog
    class Categories
      def self.const_value
        Category
      end
    end
  end
end

Admin::Blog::Categories.const_value # => 11
```

Following 2 examples above, this example ofcourse, should throw error :

```
module Blog
  class Category
    #...
  end
end

module Admin
  module Blog
    class Categories
      def self.const_value
        Category
      end
    end
  end
end

Admin::Blog::Categories.const_value
# uninitialized constant Admin::Blog::Categories::Category (NameError)
```

Read this guide [tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-algorithms-relative-references) to understand this topic.

Last to finish:

```
module Blog
  class Category
  end
end

module Admin
  module Blog
    class Categories
      def self.const_value
        ::Blog::Category
      end
    end
  end
end

Admin::Blog::Categories.const_value # => Blog::Category
```